# passing JS variable to a java class

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-1.2

I am making a transit routing project and I needed google maps to pin out the stations and the stops,,, I get the coordinates from google maps in a JavaScript,, now I need to pass these coordinates to a java class where I can make different processes on these coordinates. I am using JSF -Java server faces- on netbeans. Can anyone help me with passing these coordinates to a .java class? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are many frameworks that will help you with this. Primefaces, for example, has a google maps plugin built right in to their new JSF implementation ( http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/gmapHome.jsf ). Doing it by hand is also pretty easy. Just set up a Servlet to handle GET requests and use whatever Ajax method you would like to send the data to your Servlet. I'd start by looking for some Servlet and Ajax examples. Again, depending on what implementation of JSF you're using there may be Ajax tools built in already.

Best of luck.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a hidden input `<h:inputHidden value="#{bean.value}"/>`.
2. Update its value using javascript.
3. Process `<h:inputHidden value="#{bean.value}"/>` to update its bean value.

Here is a working example:

```java
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private String value;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        value = "SERVER SIDE VALUE";
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

```html
<h:head>
    <script>
        function updateElementValue(id,value){
            document.getElementById(id).value = value;
        }
    </script>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form id="form" prependId="false">

        <p:commandButton value="UPDATE CLIENT SIDE VALUE OF INPUT-HIDDEN"
                         onclick="updateElementValue('nameInputHiddenId',
                                                     'CLIENT SIDE VALUE');
                                                      return false;"/>
        <p:commandButton value="UPDATE SERVER SIDE VALUE OF INPUT-HIDDEN" 
                         process="@form" 
                         update="dialogId" 
                         oncomplete="dialogWidgetVar.show();" />

        <h:inputHidden id="nameInputHiddenId" value="#{bean.value}" />

        <p:dialog id="dialogId" widgetVar="dialogWidgetVar">
            <h:outputText id="nameOutputTextId" value="#{bean.value}" />
            <p:commandButton value="Yes" onclick="dialogWidgetVar.hide();" />
            <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="dialogWidgetVar.hide();"/>
        </p:dialog>

    </h:form>

</h:body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<a4j:jsFunction>` to pass `javascript` values to the managed bean. This is an example.

This is your `js` array

```
<script>
  var coordinateArray = [12, 26];
</script>
```

This is your page. Note that `sendData` is the name of your `jsFunction` and `coordinateArray.join()` converts the array to a String.

```
   <h:form>
    <a4j:commandButton value="Send" onclick="sendData(coordinateArray.join())"/>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="sendData">
      <a4j:actionparam name="param1" assignTo="#{hBean.coordinatesString}" />
    </a4j:jsFunction>
   </h:form>
```

In you managed bean

```
  String coordinatesString;
  String[] coordinatesArray;

  public String getCoordinatesString() {
    return coordinatesString;
  }

  public void setCoordinatesString(String coordinatesString) {
    this.coordinatesString = coordinatesString;
    this.coordinatesArray = coordinatesString.split(",");//This is what you need
  }
```

Edit:

---

Think `a4j:jsFunction` as a normal `javascript` function.You can put an `actionParam` inside it as in above sample. If so, it means that `jsFunction` has one argument(similar to normal javascript function argument). You give the `jsFunction` a name, and call it, using that given name like a normal `javascript` function(i.e. `funcName()`). If there is an `actionparam` inside it you should pass a parameter when you calling it(i.e. `funcName(value)`).
A `<h:form>` should not be necessarily around it. But if you want to call it when you `click` a `commandButton`, that button should be within a form. 
As you say in your comment, if the name of your coordinate array is `path` then you call the above `jsFunction` like this. `sendData(path.join())`. You don't add any `javascript` code inside the `jsFunction`. **Simply you call the `jsFunction` from your `javascript` code as you call a normal `javascript` function.**

Comment: I dont know where should i put the <h:form> ... code, I have function that puts the points in var path[],, should I put this code in this jsfunction, if yes what should be the jsFunction then? what jsFunction should contain anyways.. sorry but I am a beginner in the webapplications and i really need ur help

Comment: I added a paragraph to my answer.